# How to add String in-between list variables?

Tags: python

I am trying to add "!" after every variable in a list.
But my code only adds the series of "!" after the initial list.
For example:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

def addmark(lst):
    emptylst = []
    for n in range(0, len(lst)):
        lst.append("!")
    return lst
```

This would return [1,2,3,4,"!", "!", "!", "!"]

I want to reuturn [1, "!", 2, "!", 3, "!", 4, "!"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def addmark(lst):
    emptylst = []
    for i in lst:
        emptylst.append(i)
        emptylst.append("!")
    return emptylst
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the accepted answer using itertools:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

lst = [1, 2, 3]
marker = repeat("!")

list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lst, marker)))
>>> [1, '!', 2, '!', 3, '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using insert:**

> list.**insert** *(i, x)*
>   Insert an item at a given position. The first
>   argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>   a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a),
>   x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

Reference: [docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

**Code:**

```
def addmark(lst):
    add = 0 # needed cause after every insertion of '!' the position where you want to add the next '!' changes
    for i in range (1,len(lst)+1): # (start: adding after ls[0], finish: adding after the last element)
        lst.insert(i+add, '!')
        add += 1
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8

'''黄哥Python'''


def addmark(lst):
    result = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        result.append(item)
        result.append("!")
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [1,2,3,4]
    print addmark(lst)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of lists then flatten

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = [[i,'!'] for i in lst]
lst3 = [item for sublist in lst2 for item in sublist]
print lst2
print lst3    

>>> [[1, '!'], [2, '!'], [3, '!'], [4, '!']]
>>> [1, '!', 2, '!', 3, '!', 4, '!']
```

as a one liner:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
lst2 = [item for sublist in [[i,'!'] for i in lst] for item in sublist]
print lst2

>>> [1, '!', 2, '!', 3, '!', 4, '!']
```